# Is there an equivalent to CustomizableOutDir in Team Build 2010?

Tags: tfs, build

Is there a 2010 version of CustomizableOutDir for TFS?

I want to run a Silverlight and .NET project such as what is being talked about in this [guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458864.aspx) article, and need the CustomizableOutDir functional to do something like [this for my build](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2009/06/preserving-output-directory-structure.html) to separate out Silverlight projects from .NET projects, some of whom have the same assembly names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aaron Hallberg mentioned to me that you can change the MSBuild activity in the workflow to not set an OutDir. This worked, but caused the Binaries folder to not get a copy of the output.

*"you [...] need to modify the workflow to not set the OutDir property of the MSBuild activity.  I would suggest opening up the xaml in a text/XML editor rather than the WF designer so that you can just search for the string MSBuild.*"